# Select and change an SVG element inside an <object> tag with external JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm working on Africa map: object element in my `main.html` that contains an external SVG file.

```
<object id="afrika" data="Africa Map.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

In Africa Map.svg every country have an `id="country_name"` and `onmouseover="displayName('country_name')"`.

At the bottom of my svg file, before `</svg>` tag, I have `<text>` element where I want to print `country_name` when is mouse over a particular country.

```
<text class="label" id="country-name" x="5" y="200"> </text>
```

With my external js file I menage to select an SVG inside an `<object>` tag to change for example color of some country:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var a = document.getElementById("afrika"); 
  var svgDoc = a.contentDocument; 
  var svgItem = svgDoc.getElementById("Algeria"); 
  svgItem.setAttribute( "fill", "lime");
});
```

but when I try to use a function to add `country_name` in `<text>`

```
window.addEventListener ("load", function displayName(name) {
  var a = document.getElementById("afrika");
  var svgDoc = a.contentDocument;
  var svgName = svgDoc.getElementById("country-name");
  svgName.firstChild.data = name;
```

I am getting an error  `displayName is not defined`.

But if I put the same function in `<script>` tag in my svg file it works perfectly.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   <![CDATA[  
      function displayName(name) {
        document.getElementById('country-name').firstChild.data = name;
      }
   ]]>
</script>
```

Can someone please explain me why the function is not working in my external js file?

Comment: Try changing `window.addEventListener ("load", function displayName(name){` to `window.addEventListener("load", function()` - it could be that this needs to be an anonymous function.

Comment: @user7290573 that should work fine. as far as I'm concerned `function fnName() {}` doesn't have a syntax problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if you would be able to change the internal document of an `<object>`. Probably that's the case here. And when you put `<script>` inside of your internal document ( into SVG document itself ) it doesn't have the mentioned problem with changing document since it's not from an external file anymore.

Comment: @mrReiha you can provided it's sourced from the same domain as the parent document.

Comment: @RobertLongson I didn't mean the CORS problem. I think it's just like an `<img>` tag. You can't change the data of an `<img>` like writing something into it as asked in the OP. Kindly correct me if I'm wrong, please. You can read it since it's from the same domain, but you can't write something into it.

Comment: You are correct that you can't change the data in an <image> tag but you can if you use an <object> tag as is the case here.

Comment: Thanks all for comments, although mystery is not resolved. If I found the solution, I'll let u know.